# I'm not able to get the correct homography points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, homography

I'm trying to create homography matrix from this field:
[image]

(source image with ids:)
[image]

To the destination image:
[image]

The points for the source points are:

```
pts_src = [[ 761,  704],
 [ 910,  292],
 [1109,  544],
 [ 619,  479],
 [ 656,  373 ],
 [1329,  446],
 [  20,  559],
 [  87,  664],
 [ 238,  501],
 [ 399,  450]]
```

And the points for destination points (new image):

```
pts_dst = [[147, 330],
 [ 35 , 20],
 [147, 225],
 [ 75, 203],
 [ 35, 155],
 [147, 155],
 [ 35, 317],
 [ 75, 351],
 [ 35, 237],
 [ 35, 203]]
```

I tried to create homography matrix with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
pts_src = np.array(pts_src)
pts_dst = np.array(pts_dst)
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst) 
print(h) #homography matrix
```

And I got the following homography matrix:

```
[[ 4.00647822e-01  1.41196305e+00 -6.90548584e+02]
 [-1.28068526e-01  3.03783700e+00 -6.98945354e+02]
 [ 3.12182175e-04  4.06980322e-03  1.00000000e+00]]
```

I tried to check if the homography matrix is correct, so I used the first coordinate from the source image `(761,  704)`, and check if I get the correct coordinate in destination image, which should be `(147, 330)`. I tried to use the equation `new_x, new_y, new_z = h*(x,y,z)`:

```
p = [761,  704, 1]
print(np.matmul(h, p))
```

And I got:

```
array([ 608.36639573, 1342.23174648,    4.1027121 ])
```

Which is very far (and for some reason the `z` is `4.1`).

And I also tried the second point `(910,  292)`, and I should get `(35 , 20)`, but I got `[86.33414416, 71.5606917 ,  2.47246832]`.

Any idea why I'm not able to get the correct coordinates?

Comment: Learn a little about "homogeneous coordinates". 2D point you want is (x/z, y/z).

Comment: `cv.convertPointsFromHomogeneous`

Comment: thx @fana. It's what I needed. After dividing by z I get pretty good results, but I get few percents error. Any idea how to fix it? Is it because the points are not accurate or because the homography is not accurate?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz any idea how to use it? I see it's called 'cv2.triangulatePoints()' in python. Is it more/less/same accurate as dividing by 'z' (as fana suggested)?

Comment: what? no, those are named differently, they're different things. it, `convertPointsFromHomogeneous`, simply "divides by z". there is no room for "inaccuracy". division isn't guesswork. your question makes no sense.

Comment: use cv2.perspectiveTransform, but that's the same as dividing by z. All inaccuracies come from one or multiple of: 1. Inaccuracies in point positions (src and dst); 2. Inaccuracies in the target plane (soccer field not perfectly planar); 3. Camera lens distortion (undistort your images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was mentioned in the comments thanks to @fana - dividing the `x` and `y` coordinates by `z` `(x/z, y/z)`.